# Can a light fixture cover another junction box?

Tags: electrical

I have a relatively large light fixture (Hampton Bay 20" LED round ceiling puff) that mounts like normal to a round ceiling box.

I need to place a junction box (old work drywall box) in the ceiling near the fixture.

Can the fixture cover the junction box?
If so, should the junction box have the cover plate on or off?
If no cover, would it need screws from the fixture into the junction box?

It's not a deal breaker if I can't hide the box but it would simplify installation.

Comment: Junction boxes have to be accessible in case something needs to be serviced.

Comment: but a light fixture is covering it's own box, so can it cover more than one box?

Comment: It is common knowledge (*because it is code*) that a light fixture is attached to a box. It is not common for there to be two, nor would anybody know there was another box hidden. What is the purpose of the offending box? "*I need to place a junction box (old work drywall box) in the ceiling near the fixture.*" Why do you need to place it so near the fixture box? Perhaps it does not need to be so near.

Comment: It doesn't need to be that near. If I could hide it, it would be preferable, but it isn't a big deal. I just wanted to check before I did anything. The box is to hold a wireless light switch receiver that will not fit in the fixture or in the pancake box the fixture is attached to.

Comment: "*If I could hide it, it would be preferable*"  That is the point, Code says it must be accessible. You could technically hide one with a wall hanging or such but you **can not bury it in a wall** with out access to it. Putting a light fixture over it seems beyond a wall hanging that can easily be lifted off to access the cover to the box.

Comment: Abandon the pancake box, run the wire to a new retro fit fixture box, far enough away,  that is deep enough? There is more than one to skin a cat. Put a cover on the pancake box.

Comment: I don't necessarily want to replace the pancake box because it's centered and mounted on a furring strip. It's an attic ceiling that was finished long before my time, so I don't really know how it's framed out. To install a deeper box in that spot would require cutting out that part of the furring strip which I don't really want to do blind.

Comment: I presume the box you want to cover is metal since you said its a pancake box, correct?

Comment: The pancake box is the one the light fixture is being mounted to and is metal, the second box I wanted to cover is plastic. I ended up just putting the secondary junction box in the drywall beyond the fixture and using a blank plate.

Comment: If you have access do it from the attic and put a cover on it not an old work box. If you don’t have access it has to be accessible so putting it under the fixture would be a code violation. Accessible can be a cover designed to be removed without affecting the finish. I don’t think the fixture could be called a removable panel.